# Is it possible to build an instrument which can travel faster than light?

Tags: science

I have heard about atomic rockets in novels which have the capablity to travel faster than light. I have also heard about fictional stories where objects capable to travel faster than light.

My question is:

Is it scientifically possible to build an instrument which can travel faster than light?

Comment: Your best bet for an answer on this and other real world problems is actually [Physics.SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/).  If you were interested in how a faster-than-light device worked in a specific fictional work, that would be on-topic for here.

Comment: @dianod i like to compare the fictional reasons made and like to explore some scientific possibilities in general,thats y i placed this question here sir

Comment: @dlanod Please don't send people to Physics.SE with a common question like this without suggesting that they search the site first. We have more than a *dozen* "How about *this* scheme for going faster than light?" questions already. This is the comment re-direct version of ["don't migrate crap"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/).

Answer (score 2):

[NASA has a page on interstellar travel allowing FTL-like travel.](http://www.nasa.gov/centers/glenn/technology/warp/ideachev_prt.htm)  Note that none of those devices have been built or maybe possible.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible, given our current scientific knowledge. What we do know is that if you can travel faster than light you can travel backwards in time -- they are equivalent.